# Question about Weitzenbock formula?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

$\Delta = -d\delta - \delta d$ is the Laplace operator in the Riemann manifold $(M, g)$. I want to prove:

> $\Delta\alpha (Y) = tr D^2\alpha(Y) - Ric(X, Y)$

where $\alpha  \in A^1(M)$, $X$ its dual vector field, $Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$,.

Chosen local coordinate $(U, x)$, and $\alpha|_U = \alpha_i dx^i, X|_U = a^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, and $tr D^2 = g^{ij}(D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}} - D_{D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}})$.

By definition LHS

$\Delta\alpha = \alpha^k_{,ki}dx^i + g^{jk}(\alpha_{j,ik}-\alpha_{i,jk})dx^i $

$=  g^{jk}\alpha_{i,jk}dx^i - \alpha^hR^k_{hki}dx^i $

$=  g^{jk}\alpha_{i,jk}dx^i - \alpha^hR_{hi}dx^i$.

But when I compute the RHS, I confused about

$tr D^2\alpha = g^{ij}(D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}} - D_{D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}})\alpha $

$= g^{ij}D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}\alpha_{s,j}dx^s - g^{ij}D_{\Gamma^k_{ji}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}}\alpha $

$= g^{ij}(\alpha_{s,j})_{,i}dx^s - g^{ij}\Gamma^k_{ji}D_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}}\alpha $

$= g^{ij}\alpha_{s,ji}dx^s-g^{ij}\Gamma^k_{ji}\alpha_{s,k}dx^s$

$Ric(X, \cdot) = R_{hi}\alpha^hdx^i$

There is one more term $-g^{ij}\Gamma^k_{ji}\alpha_{s,k}dx^s$ confuse me.

Did I make wrong or this term is zero? Any help  will be appreciated.

Comment: You jumped too quickly from $D_{\partial_j}\alpha$ to $\alpha_{s,j}dx^s$ (and again with $D_{\partial_i}$) and missed the other terms of covariant derivatives here.  Remember we are acting on $1$-forms here, and $dx^s$ cannot be chosen as covariant constants on a coordinate neighbourhood unless the metric is flat.

Comment: @user10354138 I didn't choose $dx^s$ as covariant constants. $D_{\partial_i}\alpha_sdx^s = \alpha_{s,i}dx^s$ by the definition of connection and $\alpha_{s,i}$is the absolute derivative of $\alpha_s$.

Comment: You should have $D_i\alpha_s dx^s =\alpha_{s;i} dx^s= \alpha_{s,i}dx^s - \Gamma^k_{is}\alpha_k dx^s$.

Comment: @user10354138 Oh, Sorry, where my $\alpha_{s,i}$ is your $\alpha_{s;i}$, and your  $\alpha_{s,i} = \partial \alpha_s /  \partial x^i$.